# argmin in dataset containing NaN python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

```
      SGSIN VNVUT CNSHK HKHKG JPOSA
To                                 
MYPKL     1     4     8     9    13
SGSIN   NaN     3     7     8    12
VNVUT   NaN   NaN     3     4     8
CNSHK     1   NaN   NaN     1     5
HKHKG   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     3
```

Let say we have the above dataset using pandas. I want to calculate the `arg_minimum` over the first column and ignoring the `NaN`. I tried with

```
df[df[0]].idxmin()
```

but it gives

```
nan
```

but I don't get the right result then. Can someone help me?  The result I want is (in this case)

```
[0,3]
```

Comment: You never mentioned the result of performing `df[df[0]].idxmin()`?

Comment: I edit my question with the result of performing df[df[0]].idxmin()

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy's `argwhere`

```
import numpy as np

np.argwhere(df['SGSIN'].eq(df['SGSIN'].min()))

array([[0],
       [3]])
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't do the job. I get an empty stringg

Comment: I ran np.argwhere(df[df.columns[0]].eq(df[df.columns[0]].min())). btw: I am using pandas in python

Comment: @Koen something doesn't add up. np.where doesn't return a string.  Your best bet is to provide code that produces a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. That way there is no ambiguity. Per the text you provided in your question, my answer works. When I have time, I'll edit my post to demonstrate what I mean. But you may want to make that attempt sooner so that someone else might help.

Comment: I meant in fact that I get an empty array so just [[]], your answer works if the dataset does not contain NaN. If there is NaN, it gives [[]]